# Can I delete images after Facebook graph api upload?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cdn

I upload images with the graph api to friends pages:

```
FB.api('/' + friendId + '/photos', 'post', {
            message:'Why don’t you surprise your friends with a special Happy Holidays greeting on their timeline?,
            url:picUrl
        }, function(response){

            if (!response || response.error) {}
                console.log('Posting error: ' + response.error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
```

And as soon as that has happend, I see the post with an url like http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/-IMAGEID-.jpg

Does Facebook immediately put the images on a CDN and I can delete my local images on my server? Just wondering as I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  After the image is uploaded to Facebook, you no longer need to keep the image on your server.  I have personally done this many times on several projects where I have users generating images and then uploading those images to an album.

here is an old Facebook Blog article that talks a little about their CDN: http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=2406207130

Comment: Is there any page on facebook's api documentation that states this? Just beeing curious..